# how i search partial words in php and mysql with highlighted output characters

Tags: php, mysql, search

I want partial word search randomly. if result match then its give with highlighted words output
My database Records:

name : james alexender roye

description : happy birth day to you

if i search like "ja alex roy" and if i searach like "bir day you";

then i want output like : "**ja**mes **alex**ender **roy**e"; 
and "happy **bir**th **day** to **you**"

But my search not work like above its  just search one complete word not partial word.

Below my code:

```
    <?php           
    if(isset($_POST['searchbutton']))

    {


        $serach = $_POST['searchdata'];

        if($serach == "" || strlen($serach) <3){
          echo "<h4 style='color:red;'>Sorry No result Found</h4>";
        }
        else{


            $qry="select * from  tbl_services where status='Yes' and name like '%$serach%' OR description LIKE '%$serach%'";
            $res=mysql_query($qry);
        }
}
            ?>
```

My HTML CODE:

```
    <?php 
     while($pos=mysql_fetch_array($res)){    
                $name= $pos['name']; 
                $description=$pos['description']; 

    ?>

             <div class="item">

                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 bus-detail">

                        <p><?php echo $name ?></p>
                        <p><?php echo $description ?></p>

                    </div>
                 </div> 
                </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I think that the only way to do the highlighting part is to fetch the documents and compare bit by bit and apply bold if matched

Comment: highlight is second requirement first is how i search like my above mention requirement. as i wish search is not perform like my requirement